# Matlab only has 4 line styles?

Tags: matlab, plot

In the help of matlab, there are only 4 linestyles:

> '- '  Solid line (default)
>
> '--'  Dashed line
>
> ':'   Dotted line
>
> '-. ' Dash-dot line

Can I plot curves in other styles?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Not that I know of, but combine that with the different `LineWidth` and you start to have many combinations. If you need more differentiation, you can then play with the `Color`, and/or the variety of `Markers`.

Comment: Yes, by using different colors, it can make curves look different. But if you print it merely in black/white, the curves still cannot be recognized. Besides, I don't think `LineWidth` is a good choice. Thank you all the same!

Comment: I know, not only on printers. Despite what's currently available, many scientific publications are still published in B&W. A couple of workarounds are: (i) plot one line with a given style, then plot the same "downsampled" line with a specific marker (and no line at all [_example_](http://aras.ab.ca/articles/scientific/GraphEvolutionFigures/fauci1996.jpeg)). (ii) instead of a legend, add a `text` object directly on each line somewhere (works well for [_abacus type graph_](http://images.math.cnrs.fr/IMG/jpg/AbaqueAnamorphose.jpg)).

Comment: plot(x,y,'-.o') is simpler and gives the same result as @Hoki's answer.

Comment: @Yellows, yes that works if your line has a few points, but if it has 20000 points it's just going to clutter the plot. The idea is to only plot 5 to 10 markers on each line.

Comment: @Hoki "downsampled" plot with marker is really a good idea! Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following also work:

```
.-.
-^
-o
-*
:*
```

This is not an exhaustive list.

You can also use `'LineWidth',10` to make lines thicker if that helps. The marker size can also be changed using the `MarkerSize` handle.

Comment: Yeah, but if the points is too many, the markers will huddle together. In this case, the "downsampled" method is a better choice.

Comment: To be clear, these are technically not all line styles. MATLAB differentiates between a LineStyle (being the line weight) and a Marker Specifier. That said, thanks and +1!
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html